# Using Document Nodes in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, parent-child, document

I'm trying to read an xml file, for example: http://www1.skysports.com/feeds/11095/news.xml

I need to be able to `getTextContent()` for all the titles, descriptions etc that are children of `<item>` tags. There is a `<title>` tag that is not a child of an `<item>` tag that i dont want to `getTextContent()` for.

I've set up my XML reader so that i have:

```
Document doc = dbuilder.parse(xmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
String Title = document.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
```

but this method picks up the `<title>` that isnt a child of `<item>`

I could just change the `item(0)` to `item(1)` but I need this algorithm to work with various XML files that wont necessarily have the initial `<title>` without the `<item>` parent.

how can I just select those `<title>`s that are children of `<item>`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XPath instead. Makes it all a lot easier:

```
    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xp = xpf.newXPath();

    NodeList nl = (NodeList) xp.evaluate("//item/title/text()", doc,
            XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(nl.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```